# Error in fisher.test : Bug in fexact3, it[i=6]=0: negative key (kyy=91)

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have this table abd I want to analyse it statistically.

```
table(sci$category, sci$true_group)


                 mono sim_rus_nen suc_balanced suc_nen_rus suc_rus_nen
  generalization    9           3            9           4           3
  description      35          16           15          13          17
  scheme            2           1            1           1           2
  syncretism        5           3            7          16           2
  tautology         2           2            2           3           3
  substitution      1           0            0           0           0
  indefinite        7           5            5           6           9
  no_answer        30          17           18          13          19
```

So I decided to apply Fisher's exact test. But I have this error (although it's OK with chiq.square)

```
fisher.test(table(sci$category, sci$true_group))
```

> Error in fisher.test(my_tab) :    Bug in fexact3, it[i=6]=0: negative
>   key -1099365618 (kyy=91)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For larger contingency table/ counts, it gets resource intensive, to count all the worst cases to arrive at the p-value** (seems to be that error).

*So its convenient to simulate the p-values for tables larger than (2x2):*

```
df <- table(sci$category, sci$true_group)

fisher.test(df, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e6)

Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 1e+06 replicates)
data:  df
p-value = 0.1054
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

***PS:*** Choosing between Fishers exact test vs Chisq-test is a whole another discussion. I would refer you to this cross validated post for clarity: [Alternatives to chisq-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159057/alternatives-for-chi-squared-test-for-independence-for-tables-more-than-2-x-2/159063#159063)

Comment: Thanks! Is it OK to apply such simulation in chisq.test for the same data? I've chosen Fisher's because I have small number of observations, but it seems that I'd rather use Chi-squared test with simulated p-value.

Comment: Using p-value simulation in a convenient way for any statistical tests for which it gets hard to calculate all possible combinations. Choosing between `Fishers exact test vs Chisq-test` is a whole another discussion. I would refer you to this cross validated post for clarity [Fisher vs Chisq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159057/alternatives-for-chi-squared-test-for-independence-for-tables-more-than-2-x-2/159063#159063)